# How to draw an arc between two lines

Tags: c++, qt

My current implementation in code is similar to the image attached. How does one draw an arc between the vertical line (normal line) and the intersecting lines (Refractive line and incident line)? I am not sure how to go about doing this. The arc has to update as well as the refractive and incident lines move. [image: Example here]

```
void SnellsLawWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawText(QPoint(width - 100, height / 2 + 20), "Interface");
    painter.drawText(QPoint(width / 2 + 10, 20), "Normal");


    painter.drawText(QPoint(100, height / 2 - 20), "n1");
    painter.drawText(QPoint(100, height / 2 + 30), "n2");

    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, Qt::SolidLine));
    painter.drawLine(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);

    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::green, Qt::DashLine));
    painter.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);

    QLineF incidenceLine;
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, Qt::SolidLine));
    incidenceLine.setP1(QPoint(width / 2, height / 2));
    incidenceLine.setAngle(qreal(angleOfIncidence) + angleOffset);
    incidenceLine.setLength(indexLength);
    painter.drawLine(incidenceLine);
    painter.drawText(QPoint(incidenceLine.x2(), incidenceLine.y2()), theta + QString("1"));

    QLineF refractiveLine;
    refractiveLine.setP1(QPoint(width / 2, height / 2));
    refractiveLine.setAngle(qreal(angleOfRefraction) - angleOffset);
    refractiveLine.setLength(indexLength);
    painter.drawText(QPoint(refractiveLine.x2(), refractiveLine.y2()), theta + QString("2"));
    painter.drawLine(refractiveLine);   
}
```

Comment: How about [QPainter::drawPie()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPie)?

Comment: _The arc has to update as well as the refractive and incident lines move._ This is somehow regardless... For each change, you have to call `update()` which is causing a (new) call of `paintEvent()`. Nothing prevents you to paint the arc (pie) with different arguments each time.

Comment: Thank you, QPainter::drawPie() will work, implementing this tho will be a headache now.

Answer (score 3):

> QPainter::drawPie() will work, implementing this tho will be a headache now.

I'm not quite sure which detail might cause the head-ache.

There are some things you have to be aware concerning [QPainter::drawPie()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPie):

1. The rectangle describes the range of the full ellipse from which to draw a pie.
   Thus, if *a* and *b* are the horizontal and vertical radius of the ellipse, and *cx* *cy* the center point, the rectangle has to be `QRect(cx - a, cy - b, 2 * a, 2 * b)`.
2. There is a *startAngle* given in 16ths of degree.
   If the angle alpha is stored as a floating point, the startAngle can be computed by `(int)(alpha * 16)`.
3. Instead of the end angle the *spanAngle* is given as second argument. The span angle is the difference of end and start angle. It's given in 16ths of degree as well.
4. For a pie of a circle, just use the radius *r* for *a* and *b*.
   The circle is just a special case of an ellipse.

Example:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class PieWidget: public QWidget {

  private:
    int _alpha, _omega; // start/end angle in degree

  public:
    PieWidget(QWidget* pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent)
    { }

    virtual ~PieWidget() = default;

    PieWidget(const PieWidget&) = delete;
    PieWidget& operator=(const PieWidget&) = delete;

    void setAngles(int alpha, int omega)
    {
      _alpha = alpha; _omega = omega;
      update();
    }

  protected:
    virtual QSize sizeHint() const override { return QSize(20, 20); }

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent) override;
};

void PieWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent)
{
  const int w = width(), h = height();
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  qPainter.setPen(Qt::blue);
  qPainter.setBrush(Qt::yellow);
  const int startAngle = _alpha * 16;
  const int spanAngle = (_omega - _alpha) % 360 * 16;
  qPainter.drawPie(0, 0, w, h, startAngle, spanAngle);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  PieWidget qPie;
  qPie.setWindowTitle("QPainter::pie()");
  qPie.resize(256, 256);
  qPie.show();
  // setup animation
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(50); // 20/s seems reasonable
  int alpha = 0, omega = 0;
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      qPie.setAngles(alpha, omega);
      alpha += 10; alpha %= 360;
      omega += 5; omega %= 360;
    });
  qTimer.start();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of testQWidgetQPainterPie (GIF Animation)]